# PHP Exchanging numbers for words

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
for($n=1; $n<=100; $n++)
{
    echo $n . '<br />';
}
```

How could I change it so it shows a word for:

multiples of three

multiples of three and five

Comment: As 3 and 5 are prime numbers, you could simply say multiples of 15.

Comment: What is the result like?

Comment: The FizzBuzz problem? http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/fizzbuzz-the-programmers-stairway-to-heaven.html :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($n=1; $n<=100; $n++)
{
    $multiplies = '';
    for($m=1; $m<=$n; $m++){
        if ($n % $m == 0){
          $multiplies .= $m .' ';
        }

    }
    echo $n . ' multiplies by: '  $multiplies .'<br />';
}
```

This is general solution to check **ALL numbers from the range** for being multiplies for current number.

You can make a function from this code:

```
function ShowMultiplies($range){}
```

So in code you will use `$range` instread of 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($n=1; $n<=100; $n++)
{
    echo $n . '<br />';
    if ($n % 3 == 0) {
        echo "word<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What about 'three and five' part?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
for($n=1; $n<=100; $n++)
{
    if ($n % 3 === 0) {
       echo $n . ' is multiples of three<br />';
    }
    if ($n % 3 === 0 && $n % 5 === 0) {
       echo $n . ' is multiples of three and five<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How could I make it show 1-100 and instead of the $n just show the text?